# How transform a many to many relationship into a queryset?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I have a model in Django related to another model with a *ManyToManyField*. I'd like to retrieve all elements of *ManyToManyField*.

Here are the models :

```
class Personnel(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    adresse = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name=_("Adresse"))
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=15, verbose_name=_("Téléphone"))
    dossiermedical = models.ManyToManyField("DossierMedical",  related_name=_("travaille_sur"))

class DossierMedical(models.Model):
    patient = models.OneToOneField("Patient", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

In the Django shell, I did the following:

```
p = Personnel.objects.get(pk=User.objects.get(pk=1))
d = p.dossiermedical.all()
<QuerySet []>
```

However, when I'm Django admin for this *Personnel*, you have : [image]

**Response**

Basically, the display in the image has nothing to do with the linked *DossierMedical* objects. To add objects, you should modify the admin page like this :

```
class PersonnelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     model= Personnel
     filter_horizontal = ('dossiermedical',)
```

After that, you just have to register it and go on the autogenerated admin page that django provides.

Comment: Are you sure that you have DossierMedical for user with id 1?

Comment: First of all: you're doing it correctly. So, this is probably a data problem: either in the Django shell, `p` is not the same as what you've checked in the Django Admin or you are working in different environments where this Personnel  object has different data.

Comment: @Risadinha Yes but in this case, he is trying to get all DossierMedical for Personel with user_id = 1. My question is not about Personnel with user_id=1, but for DossierMedical for that Personel .

Comment: Oddly enough, when I check on the admin page, I see the same name as p returns: < Infirmier (11103939) >. I also did some queries on other models and they return correct data

Comment: @AlexandreManeta unless the name is unique, the most certain check is the PK - so the number in the admin URL detail view against `p.pk` in the console for the same database instance. Have you any Admin customizations for that view? How do you generate that output that you have posted - can you provide the code that creates it?

Comment: @Risadinha The output in the image is generated by the django autogenerated admin page. For the *pk*, they are both the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `ModelName.objects.get(pk=1)` anymore, because it raising exceptions. Use `ModelName.objects.filter(pk=1).first()` or `django.shortcuts.get_object_or_404(ModelName, pk=1)` instead.

It's a good practice to override `__str__` function for your models like so:

```py
class Personnel(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    adresse = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name=_("Adresse"))
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=15, verbose_name=_("Téléphone"))
    dossiermedical = models.ManyToManyField("DossierMedical",  related_name=_("travaille_sur"))

    def __str__(self):
        return f'#{self.pk} {self.user.full_name}'

class DossierMedical(models.Model):
    patient = models.OneToOneField("Patient", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'#{self.pk} {self.patient.full_name}'
```

Also you can add an inline for `DossierMedical` model and place it to 'inlines' field of `PersonnelAdmin` as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects).

Answer (score 0):

Just try it with filter.
p = Personnel.objects.filter(pk=User.objects.get(pk=1))